# Problems about torch.nn.DataParallel

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new in deep learning area. Now I am reproducing a paper’s codes. since they use several GPUs, there is a command `torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids= args.gpus).cuda()` in codes. But I only have one GPU, what
should I change this code to match up my GPU?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

`DataParallel` should work on a single GPU as well, but you should check if `args.gpus` only contains the id of the device that is to be used (should be 0) or `None`.
Choosing `None` will make the module use all available devices.

Also you could remove `DataParallel` as you do not need it and move the model to GPU only by calling `model.cuda()` or, as I prefer, `model.to(device)` where `device` is the device's name.

**Example:**

This example shows how to use a model on a single GPU, setting the device using `.to()` instead of `.cuda()`.

```py
from torch import nn
import torch

# Set device to cuda if cuda is available
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Create model
model = nn.Sequential(
  nn.Conv2d(1,20,5),
  nn.ReLU(),
  nn.Conv2d(20,64,5),
  nn.ReLU()
)

# moving model to GPU
model.to(device)
```

If you want to use `DataParallel` you could do it like this

```py
# Optional DataParallel, not needed for single GPU usage
model1 = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[0]).to(device)
# Or, using default 'device_ids=None'
model1 = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).to(device)
```