# DataParallel multi-gpu RuntimeError: chunk expects at least a 1-dimensional tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, multi-gpu

I am trying to run my model on multiple gpus using DataParallel by setting `model = nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()`, but everytime getting this error -

> RuntimeError: chunk expects at least a 1-dimensional tensor (chunk at
>   /pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp:184).

My code is correct. Does anyone know what's wrong?

I have tried setting `device_ids=[0,1]` parameter and also `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` on the terminal. Also tried different batch sizes.

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663358/problems-about-torch-nn-dataparallel . I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

To identify the problem, you should check the shape of your input data for each mini-batch. The documentation says, `nn.DataParallel` splits the input tensor in `dim0` and sends each chunk to the specified GPUs. From the error message, it seems you are trying to pass a 0-dimensional tensor.

One possible reason can be if you have a mini-batch with `n` examples and you are running your program on more than `n` GPUs, then you will get this error.

Let's consider the following scenario.

- Total training examples = 161, Batch size = 80, total mini-batches = 3
- Number of GPUs specified for DataParallel = 3

Now, in the above scenario, in the 3rd mini-batch, there will be 1 example. So, it is not possible to send chunks to all the specific GPUs and you will receive the error message. So, please check if you are not a victim of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

1. The batch size should be an integer multiple of the number of GPUs.
   OR
2. Check if you are passing a scalar value in the arguments which is of 0 shape. You can reshape that tensor to size 1 using .reshape(1)